# PHP Server URL or Path to dynamically set CSS file

Tags: php, html, css

I have some problems with the css file when including PHP pages so I need to set the full server path here like this:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];?>/css/cssfile.css">
```

The problem is that the css file is not in root but like this:

```
domain.com / folder / subfolder / css / cssfile.css
```

Because I run the same copy of the design and the names of the folders and subfolders are different I would like to set the full path of the css file / absolute ) but in PHP in some way

I tried the example above but is not working. What I need is something like

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
    href="<?php echo $_SERVER["
GET CURRENT DOMAIN / FOLDER / SUBFOLDER"];?>/engine/default.css">
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The code below will give you http://example.com or https://example.com.

```
$domain = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

Now you can can append your static path.

```
$css_url = $domain . '/my/dir/css/cssfile.css';
```

Hope this is helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable/constant as

```
$css_path = '../../tosuit';
```

Then use it in your scripts as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="<?php echo $css_path;?>/engine/default.css">
```